# Lesquelles des phrases citées dans les détails sont les mieux tournées ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Veuillez d’emblée excuser le contexte, c’est une idée qui m’a traversé l’esprit et elle me trotte depuis un moment. (Fictif)

> Tu aurais prétendument demandé à Natasha si elle s’envoyait en l’air avec Chantal, comme moi (Pretzel).

> Tu aurais prétendument demandé à Natasha si, comme moi (Pretzel), elle s’envoyait en l’air avec Chantal.

> Tu aurais prétendument demandé à Natasha si, comme Pretzel (moi), elle s’envoyait en l’air avec Chantal.

> Tu aurais prétendument dit à Natasha: est-ce que, comme Pretzel (moi), tu t’envoies en l’air avec Chantal.

> Tu aurais prétendument dit à Natasha: est-ce que tu t’envoies en l’air avec Chantal, comme Pretzel (moi).

> Tu aurais prétendument dit à Natasha: est-ce que, comme Pretzel et Chantal, Chantal et toi vous envoyez en l’air.

> Tu aurais prétendument dit à Natasha: est-ce que Chantal et toi vous envoyez en l’air, comme Pretzel et Chantal.

Si vous aviez à dire quelque chose du genre à l’oral, de quelle façon formuleriez la phrase?

D’autres tournures:

> Tu aurais laissé entendre à Natasha que je m’envoyais en l’air avec Chantal?

> Tu aurais laissé entendre à Natasha que Chantal et moi nous envoyions en l’air?

***Certaines variantes sont en fait les mêmes phrases, à l’exception près qu’un complément d’objet a été déplacé. Pour celles-ci, je me demande juste quel position du complément constitue le meilleur choix esthétiquement parlant.

N’hésitez pas à me présentez d’autres manières de donner corps à cette idée et par-dessus tout m’écrire ce que vous auriez dit à l’oral spontanément sans vous creuser l’esprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Il paraît que tu as demandé à Natasha si elle s'envoie en l'air avec Chantal, comme cette dernière le fait avec Pretzel ?*

L'adverbe "prétendument" est plus difficile à comprendre que "Il paraît que".

Comment: *Prétendument* est plus insidieux, plus lourd de conséquence et de sous-entendus que *Il paraît que*, proche des *racontars*.